# Fill description textbox on the basis of value selected in partnumber texbox, where partnumber texbox is AutoCompleteCustomSource

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have 2 textboxes txtPartNum and txtDesc. partnumber is autocomplete from database

```
public class PartNumbers
        {
            public string parts { get; set; }
            public string descr { get; set; }
        }

List<PartNumbers> _partNum = new List<PartNumbers>();

public void partNumberLoad()
        {
            try
            {
                string query = "select itmPartNumber, itemDescr from vstItems";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, MainClass.con);
                if (MainClass.con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    MainClass.con.Open();
                SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                AutoCompleteStringCollection autoPart = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    autoPart.Add(sdr["itmPartNumber"].ToString());
                    PartNumbers partNumbers = new PartNumbers { parts = sdr["itmPartNumber"].ToString(), descr = sdr["itemDescr"].ToString() };
                    _partNum.Add(partNumbers);
                }
                sdr.Close();
                cmd.Connection.Close();
                txtPartNum.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
                txtPartNum.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                txtPartNum.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoPart;                
            }
```

i have the partnumber and description saved in list _partNum. how do i get the description text box filled on the basis of partnumber selected on textChanged or keyDown event. code suggestion please.?

Comment: you take the partnumer from your textbox, filter the underlyind data collection extract the approriate element and write the description into your other textbox. Please try this and post the code if you encounter any difficulties

Comment: @MongZhu sample code please

Comment: " sample code please" sorry mate, but we are not here to write the entire code for you or do you work. Write the code, post it here, explain the problems that you have encountered, then we consider to invest **our free time** to help you.

Comment: @MongZhu Thanks for the first comment sir, i managed to do it

Comment: Glad to hear :) happy coding mate